# SonarQube:Quality gate failed

Tags: java, sonarqube

Quality gate of my application on sonarqube is failed. It's showing "Coverage on New Code
is less than 80.0%"
my application have unit test cases, but sonar is not configured to cover those test cases. 
I am confused about this problem, as this is the actual problem or not because some time before quality gate was passed with same code and now it's showing falied.

Comment: As the QG states, it is about "new code", so the old, already passed code is not considered. It will only check the code coverage for all new code since the last check. Verify that your unit tests are executed by your build script, which will also involve Sonar.

Comment: Can you please tell how to execute unit test along with the build script?

Comment: I assume you are using some kind of build tool, Maven, Ant, Gradle with or without Hudson / Jenkins. It contains the definition and instruction on how to build the code. Most times, after building, you will execute unit tests, then, maybe, integration tests. With plugins like Surefire you can create reports and such. And finally Sonar is triggered to create analysis and to also analyse the test results and so on. Do you use any of the above mentioned tools? Ant, Maven, Gradle?

Comment: yes, I use maven

Comment: Then check your pom file if and how it is interacting with sonar.